# Why getInputStream() is not overridden in HttpURLConnection of Dalvik?

Tags: java, android, dalvik

I want figure out when the getInputStream fire the connect method, but this HttpUrlConnection class doesn’t overide the getInputStream. How it works? I don't see any else clue

~ANDROID_HOME/sources/android-19/java/net/URLConnection#getInputStream

```
 /**
 * Returns an {@code InputStream} for reading data from the resource pointed by
 * this {@code URLConnection}. It throws an UnknownServiceException by
 * default. This method must be overridden by its subclasses.
 *
 * @return the InputStream to read data from.
 * @throws IOException
 *             if no InputStream could be created.
 */
public InputStream getInputStream() throws IOException {
    throw new UnknownServiceException("Does not support writing to the input stream");
}
```

but in ~ANDROID_HOME/sources/android-19/java/net/HttpURLConnection.java, the getInputStream is  not overridden.

https://android.googlesource.com/platform/libcore/+/android-4.4.2_r2/luni/src/main/java/java/net/HttpURLConnection.java
[image]

Comment: prolly because what you really get from URL.openConnection() is not returning HttpURLConnection but fx: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/libcore/+/android-4.3.1_r1/luni/src/main/java/libcore/net/http/HttpURLConnectionImpl.java

Comment: @Selvin uh,there is no such HttpURLConnectionImpl.java in the luni package either.

Comment: @log1000: open the source file link.  Note the class is not marked "public".  It's in luni (look at the file path in the URL), but not directly accessible to an app.

Comment: @fadden hi, what make me confused is this https://android.googlesource.com/platform/libcore/+/android-4.4.2_r2/luni/src/main/java/java/net/HttpURLConnection.java

Comment: @EJP I want figure out when the getInputStream fire the connect method, but this HttpUrlConnection class doesn’t overide the getInputStream. How it works?  I don't see any else clue... Thanks

Comment: Ah.  That particular file went away last year: https://android-review.googlesource.com/#/c/54970/ .  At any rate, you don't create an instance of HttpURLConnection; you call `URL.openConnection()`, which creates an appropriate instance.  The easiest way to figure out what it returns is to call it and examine the object you get back with reflection (`obj.getClass().getName()`).  Once you have the name of the concrete class you can use that as a starting point to dig through the sources.

Comment: @fadden thanks a lot. may i ask about more ? I notice that the okHttp source code is placed in the `com.squareup.okhttp` package. But on devices it refer to  `String name = "com.android.okhttp.HttpHandler";`   why?

Comment: ok, i see it. `java.protocol.handler.pkgs`

Answer (score 1):

Because HttpURLConnection is itself abstract, and is implemented by a class you haven't seen yet which does override that method.